# How to make people understand my programming idea

Tags: oop, software-design, presentation

So, I working on a problem at my workplace, that is a big company with a serious CNC shopfloor. Here I thought I could make the life much easier with a little software. I have the conception, I put a lot of work in it together with my helpful friends and here is the point, when I suppose to explain it to my leaders.

The problem is, I've never made anything like this before. So I don't know the way. I should use UML-diagrams and use cases, class diagrams etc? Or which is a preferred way?

Comment: A mixture of all is useful, if they understand it, but time consuming. First try telling them verbally what you want to do and get feedback before you put to much effort into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the management perspective you could explain why your programm is efficient and required to optimise the workflow. Creating a presentation could help you make the idea of the application clear and bring it in a form which is understandable.

Comment: Ok, it sounds good, thanks for the fast reaction! It's better to make it on paper, or rather on pc?

Comment: I would prefer a digitial presentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I will go in priorities for activities diagram. You create an activity diagram of the old flow and another with the new flow. You show both to your manager and you compare them. Normally your program will minimise steps inside the new flow. Then you can say that with less steps to manage there will be more money to earn for your manager and you at the end :)